# How to call a DialogFragment on Preference click event?

Tags: android, dialogfragment, onpreferenceclicklistener

I am making an Alarm app on android. I am newbie in Android. I want to call the Time Picker dialog fragment when one of the Preferences is clicked. I already have created a class which creates the dialog. The code which i am using to call the dialog box is:

```
TimePickerFragment newFragment=new TimePickerFragment();
newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");`
```

The above code works for button click event but not for preference click.

Comment: could you ensure that the click listener is working at all by removing the above code & just system outting a test message

Answer (score 0):

If you have made the Preference Activity then try it once

just Override -

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen, Preference preference) {

    String key = preference.getKey();
    //check the key and open dialog

    return super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preferenceScreen, preference);
}
```